# Aurelia & Typescript injection and inheritance

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, aurelia

I am working with Aurelia and Typescript and I'm trying to achieve the following thing: have a base class called `Parent`, extend this class in a class called `Child` and then inject an instance of `Child` in another class.
Here's the setup:

```
//file1

export class Parent {
    constructor() {
        debugger;
    }
}

//file2
import {Parent} from "file1";
export class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        debugger;
    }
}

//file3
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {Child} from "file2";

@inject(Child)
export class Home {
    private child: Child;
    constructor(_child: Child) {
        this.child = _child;
        debugger;
    }
}
```

However, when I do this and instantiate `Home`, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

along with `ERROR [app-router] Router navigation failed, and no previous location could be restored.`

Now, the first error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` gives me a reference to `file1.js` at the first line. (which strangely contains the html code from the index of the application).

Now, if I take the injection out of `file3` and make something like this:

```
//@inject(Child)
export class Home {
    private child: Child;
    constructor() {
        this.child =  new Child(); //here I don't inject, I just 
//instantiate a new object of type Child - still the same error
        debugger;
    }
}
```

I get exactly the same error, so it doesn't seem to be injection related.

So, how can I have a base class called `Parent`, extend this class in a class called `Child` and then inject an instance of `Child` in another class?

Or is something in my approach that is not right?

Thanks!

UPDATE: The simple fact of having a the call for a `new Child()` breakes everything, it doesn't matterr if it is called at the loading of the page, in the constructor, or if it is in a method on a button. It breakes when loading.

```
   buttonMethod(){
     var x = new Child();  //it breakes the same way
}
```

Now if I move the `Child` class in the same file as `Home` and `file3` looks like this:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {Parent} from "file1";

export class Home {
    child: Child;
    constructor() {
        this.child = new Child();
        debugger;
     }
}


export class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        debugger;
    }
}
```

and I instantiate it like this it works. However, when I try to inject it, so:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {Parent} from "file1";

@inject(Child)
export class Home {
    child: Child;
    constructor(_child: Child) {
        this.child = _child;
        debugger;
     }
}


export class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        debugger;
    }
}
```

I get: `inner error: Error: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?`

In the end I want to have them in separate files, but it is a start making it work so:)
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting the full `absolute path` to `file1`? Something like `absolute/path/to/file1`?

Comment: Also take a look at "@autoInject"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the Typescript compiler finds `file1` because it is in the `.csproj` file so it doesn't need the full path, but at runtime, the `Aurelia framework` finds the file (after the typescript code is transpiled) something like `localhost/file1.js`. So you have 2 possibilities: either create a `tsd.json` in the `typings` folder (assuming you are using AMD module system) in which to set the absolute paths for your typescript definitions or always write the full path when importing custom typings.